# Why do I get this error in Release build: This type is not supported on this platform INullableConverterFactory

Tags: xamarin, automapper

Using Xamarin XS v5.5, AutoMapper v3.2.1,
I get this runtime error in Release build (not in Debug):
`This type is not supported on this platform INullableConverterFactory`

```
[mono-rt] [ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.TypeInitializationException: 
  An exception was thrown by the type initializer for AutoMapper.Mappers.MapperRegistry --->
  System.TypeInitializationException: 
  An exception was thrown by the type initializer for AutoMapper.Mappers.EnumMapper --->
  System.PlatformNotSupportedException: This type is not supported on this platform INullableConverterFactory
[mono-rt]   at AutoMapper.Internal.PlatformAdapter.Resolve[INullableConverterFactory] (Boolean throwIfNotFound) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
[mono-rt]   at AutoMapper.Mappers.EnumMapper..cctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
[mono-rt]   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
[mono-rt]   at AutoMapper.Mappers.MapperRegistry..cctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
[mono-rt]   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
[mono-rt]   at AutoMapper.Mapper.Reset () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
[mono-rt]   at AutoMapper.Mapper.Initialize (System.Action`1 action) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
[mono-rt]   at MyApp.Android.MainActivity.ConfigMapper () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
[mono-rt]   at MyApp.Android.MainActivity.OnCreate (Android.OS.Bundle bundle) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
[mono-rt]   at Android.App.Activity.n_OnCreate_Landroid_os_Bundle_ (IntPtr jnienv, IntPtr native__this, IntPtr native_savedInstanceState) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
[mono-rt]   at (wrapper dynamic-method) object:3cc570cf-1f33-4513-b6e4-0e910820d0ba (intptr,intptr,intptr)
```

What could the issue be?

Comment: Are you sure all assemblies are copied? Guessing based on [this](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/issues/370#ref-issue-12520648)

Comment: Ever figure this one out? ive inherited a xamarin project and when im trying to release a new version im getting a similar error

Comment: @InitLipton, no sorry, I don't remember what the cause was. Most likely a XS Studio bug that has been fixed in later builds. Haven't experienced it since I posted the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's most likely the linker removing that type from the AutoMapper assembly..

Usually RELEASE mode has the linker set to SDK Assemblies or ALL Assemblies where as DEBUG doesn't do any linking

Check here how to modify what's linked
https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/advanced/custom_linking/

I had the same exception and adding this fellow in fixed it

```
<assembly fullname="AutoMapper">
   <type fullname="*INullableConverterFactory*" />
   <type fullname="*MappingExpression*" />
</assembly>
```